# jQuery connected sortable - click to move not working correctly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have two connected sortable lists using jQuery UI and I made it that when you click on an element in one list, it will add it to the bottom of the other list and vice-versa. The problem I am facing is that it works one way, but not the other. When I click on an item in the first list it moves it to the other list correctly. When I try to go the other way it appends the item to itself. This fiddle demonstrates the problem I am having: http://jsfiddle.net/qcF9G/. Here is the code as well:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    EXCLUDE
    <ul id="exclude" class="connectedSortable">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="container">
    INCLUDE
    <ul id="include" class="connectedSortable"></ul>
</div>
```

**Javascript (jQuery)**

```
$("#exclude, #include").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    distance: 10
}).disableSelection();

$("#exclude li").click(function() {
    $(this).detach().appendTo("#include");
});

$("#include li").click(function() {
    $(this).detach().appendTo("#exclude");
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("li").click(function() {
    if ($(this).closest("ul").attr("id") === "exclude"){
        $(this).appendTo("#include");
    }
    else {
        $(this).appendTo("#exclude");
    }
});
```

I tested it on JS fiddle and it works.

The JS you posted was adding the click listeners ONLY WHEN YOU UPDATED. Since there were no elements inside the include unordered list, none of the list items inside the include ul were listening for clicks.

For example, try this html with the same js you had before:

```
<div class="container">
    EXCLUDE
    <ul id="exclude" class="connectedSortable">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="container">
    INCLUDE
    <ul id="include" class="connectedSortable">
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Item 4 and 5 will move to exclude and only stay there. 1, 2, and 3 will only move to include and stay there

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it was very helpful! I changed my code to update the click listener when an item is clicked but I was wondering if there are any downsides to my method compared to the solution you provided. Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qcF9G/17/